# error while loading shared libraries: libOpenCL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, centos-7

I'm trying to run DaVinci Resolve on Centos 7, but when I start the program from the terminal I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libOpenCL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

As best as I can tell, the library isn't installed on my system. When I tried to run `yum install libOpenCl` it said the library doesn't exist. How can I get this library installed on my machine?

Comment: OpenCL implementations depend on your GPU/CPU (or Intel/AMD have CPU ones), you'll need to install from manufacturer sites.

Answer (score 23):

For Ubuntu, try:

[How to install libOpenCL.so on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796770/how-to-install-libopencl-so-on-ubuntu)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

Comment: did it with apt-get and it helped.

Comment: this is weird. I thought Resolve was a professionally designed program, yet the install instructions said nothing of this - why

Comment: This led me to installing `ocl-icd` on manjaro to get DaVinci Resolve 16 started even though `opencl-mesa` wa installed.

Answer (score 1):

hi I noticed that my Davinci Resolve crashed with an OpenCL Clang message so on ubuntu this fixed it for me `sudo apt install libopencl-clang-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Note: Below answer is to those who came across dependency related error while installing Graphics / OpenCL related errors. Hope the post saves times for someone facing similar issue.

While installing a graphic application in command line, it returned with errors related to `OpenCL` and `nVidia`. And had spent lot of time searching for a solution.

To fix the error, you can run the below command in ubuntu terminal

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```